# Buddy Secondary Life Support System (BSLSS) on American suits

Tags: iss, spacesuits, life-support, united-states

Is the Buddy Secondary Life Support System (BSLSS) available in today's American-made spacesuits used on the International Space Station?

The BSLSS enables one astronaut to provide life support (oxygen and coolant) from his space suit via a specialized hose to another astronaut in case of an emergency during a spacewalk.

I think I saw something like that in the Russian Orlan space suits.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such capability in the Shuttle / ISS era US EVA suits (Extravehicular Mobility Units - EMUs).

The suit contains a separate Secondary Oxygen Pack that is only used in the case of emergency. It provides approximately 30 minutes of O2 - enough to return to the vehicle. But there is no cross connection capability to another suit.

[Source](https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/188963main_Extravehicular_Mobility_Unit.pdf) (old, and for kids, but still the best description on the internet I know of)

Edit: It's hard to prove a negative, but I can also offer up the [EVA Checklist](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/492872main_EVA_G_H_20.pdf).  If you look at the Cuff Checklist (which is the checklist attached to the crewmember's wrist and which contains emergency response procedures) there is no reference to any buddy-breathing system.  Here's the table of contents.

[image]

SUIT P EMERG just sends you to ABORT EVA which sends you back inside. So does SOP O2 ON which indicates the Secondary Oxygen Pack has been activated.